# Parallel debugging - xdebug and phpstorm

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I try to do parallel debugging. I use [PhpStorm debugging tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A) (about 30 minute and more) with frontend.php and backend.php files:

**frontend.php** file:

```
<?php

$personJson = file_get_contents('http://localhost:777/projects/debug-both/backend.php/backend.php');
$person = json_decode($personJson);

var_dump($person);
```

**backend.php** file:

```
<?php

class Person {
    public $name;
    public $email;
}

$person = new Person();

$person->name = 'Something';
$person->email = 'something@something.com';

echo json_encode($person);
```

I use zero configuration method. When I launch frontend file in browser with debug session, in PhpStorm debugging session is being start but I cannot step over in line:

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost:777/projects/debug-both/backend.php/backend.php');
```

to go to the `backend.php` file as in tutorial (31:36 in the video).

Question: how to make it working? In this video there is nothing more and it seems it should work right away but it doesn't.

I include my xdebug configuration from phpinfo [image: xdebug configuration from phpinfo] and xdebug configuration in PhpStorm [image: xdebug configuration in PhpStorm]

Comment: So .. you are trying to debug more than one request at the same time (1st script calls 2nd, and you want to debug it as well). Is that correct? If so -- show your xdebug settings (xdebug section of phpinfo() output) as well as screenshot of "Settings | PHP | Debug"

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks you for your interest. That's exactly I want to achieve. I added screenshots to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** `Settings | PHP | Debug | Max simultaneous connections` -- should be more than 1. You already have it set.

**2.** `xdebug.remote_autostart` should be `1` / `on`. This will tell xdebug to attempt to debug **every single request** regardless of debug cookie/parameter.

This is needed as your 2nd script will not receive the same cookies/parameters as original script (as it is technically separate request).

Yes, this option may not convenient for day-to-day development as it will attempt to debug every single request, and if debug client is not available ... you will see around 1 sec delay in script execution.

**The alternative approach** (in your specific case) would be adding xdebug GET parameter (e.g. `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1`) into URL when calling for 2nd script. This will tell xdebug to debug this request. For example:

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost:777/projects/debug-both/backend.php/backend.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1');
```

As you can see this approach requires modifying your code (requested URLs). Quite often this is not desired.

**Yet another alternative** is to set breakpoint programmatically by adding `xdebug_break();`. This should trigger debugger even without those extra params/cookies or `remote_autostart` setting.

The downside is the same: code manipulation is required. The good point -- it should be easier to do compared to altering URLs (+ much easier to read/understand what is going on).

Comment: Thank you very much for very detailed answer. In my case changing `xdebug.remote_autostart` was the thing I needed.